# Continuous Delivery of NodeJS App using AWS Services

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

Can someone share the thoughts that what could be the best way to do CI/CD of a NodeJS app using only AWS Services.

I have gone through some blogs but I did not find any where complete AWS Services stack has been used.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Please advise what could be done otherwise if not AWS Services stack completely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use AWS services, then your option is to use AWS Code Pipeline which is tailor made for doing CI/CD on AWS. It integrates with other AWS services such as CodeCommit, CodeDeploy. Code Pipeline can also work with other non-AWS platforms such as Jenkins and GitHub. You can have a look at the aws [official documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) for details on how to implement a CI/CD pipeline.